# UIActionSheet works fine in iOS6 but crashes in iOS7 -- data structures were at fault

Tags: ios, pdf, ios7, uiactionsheet

**EDIT**: The error is with the data structures that are being used during PDF generation. I'll be able to debug it once I can get a copy of OSX that supports iOS7. Thanks for all the help everyone!

At work I have Mac dedicated to working on iOS 6 apps. So far it hasn't been possible to update to a newer version of OSX so my version of XCode can't be upgraded to support iOS7 naturally. So long story short I can't debug iOS7 apps, so I am not sure why the app is crashing.

I have a UIActionSheet. I used to be using one with those completion blocks but was trying to debug so I have stripped everything away to just the basic barebones and it still crashes when I click on the button.

```
UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Send by Email", @"Send To...", @"Open In...", nil ];
[actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
```

That's just sitting on the end of a PDF generation method.

Any ideas? I've been researching this all afternoon and I haven't found any reason why it would stop working like this. I did try storing the action sheet as data in the view controller so the reference was being kept, but to no avail.

I am using ARC.

**EDIT:** I tried an UIAlertView with the same results. Maybe it's the PDF context ruining things somehow?

Thanks for all the help everyone.

**EDIT:** Big breakthrough in solving this one: When commenting out my PDF generation code that's before my action sheet/modal dialog/alert view, it opens without complaint. So it's some kind of hybrid issue, and I'll post the majority of my method here so everybody can see what's up:

```
-(void)shareTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (actionSheet.isVisible)
        return;

    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No mail setup" message:@"You must setup your email in the main settings app before you can share." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    for( NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows )       
    {
        // should only get run once due to UI
        Calculation* calc = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *filename = [calc.name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *path = [[[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"ipc"];
        [[PPCalculation sharedInstance] openCalculation:path];
    }
    [[PPCalculation sharedInstance] calculate];

    // let's generate the PDF here!
    NSMutableData* pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, CGRectZero, nil );
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    // 200 lines of drawing commands here

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // save to file
    NSString* path;
    for( NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows )
    {
        // should only get run once due to UI
        Calculation* calc = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString* filename = [calc.name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        path = [[[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"pdf"];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                contents:pdfData
                                              attributes:nil];
    }

    // ActionSheet, modal dialog, composer dialog, alert view, all of them crash when I try to put them here
    UIActionSheet* sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Send By Email", nil];
    [sheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks again guys.

**EDIT**: It seems that, from my investigation and commenting things out line by line and sending them to the device over TestFlight that it's the internal data structures somehow not working properly, which is strange, as the rest of the app works fine. I probably will get a copy of Mountain Lion or something so I can debug this thing properly.

Comment: What's the crash error message?

Comment: That's my problem. I can't debug on it as the xcode version I'm running is too old and this is the boss' iPhone. :(. So it just crashes to desktop without message as that's how they work apparently.

Comment: The `[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil: delegate:nil` part looks very weird to begin with. You should make sure you learn proper message calling in Objective-C. Try `[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"mytitle" delegate:nil` or `[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil`.

Comment: This is a universal app. And thanks Jonny, that was a bad copy/paste on my part (had to type manually due to the Mac not letting me log into SO). I did have a go at your suggestions and it didn't like me.

Comment: @Kilkakon:have you tried `showFromToolbar:` method?

Comment: That seems not caused by UIActionSheet, you could comment last two lines code and test again, checkout if the app still crash in iOS 7. if that, maybe the problem occurred at pdf drawing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By sheer trial and error and commenting out code, I have narrowed it down to the PDF generation itself. Somewhere in the guts of the C++ data structures something is happening that is making iOS7 sad but the others fine. I've managed to convince the boss to order Mountain Lion so once that arrives I can build for iOS7 directly and debug it properly.

Comment: In the end, it was using strcpy on a literal C string. Fine on the older operating systems, iOS7 can't deal. It's bad practice anyway I admit so buffers work well on everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code... May be it will help you...

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Send by Email", @"Send To...", @"Open In...", nil];
//actionSheet.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
actionSheet.tag = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;
[actionSheet showFromRect:[(UIButton*)sender frame] inView:[(UIButton*)sender superview] animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm clicking from a UIBarButtonItem rather than a normal button! So I can't get the sender's frame like that.

Answer (score -1):

Try This it will help yo

your barbutton action method :

```
UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil: delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Send by Email", @"Send To...", @"Open In...", nil ];

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```